# Where are Man -pages for the module MySQLdb in Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I would like to get [Python's documentation](http://docs.python.org/) for MySQLdb in Man -format such that I can read them in terminal.

**Where are Man -pages for MySQLdb in Python?**

Comment: Please, create a tag for MySQLdb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using pydoc?  Try running the following command.

```
pydoc MySQLdb
```

That should give you something close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to convert it yourself. MySQLdb doesn't come with man pages (as far as I know) but the documentation can be accessed e.g. from the [project page](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/). The user guide has a format reasonably similar to a man page so you could probably try to work with that.

Note that you can just download the user guide and use an HTML-aware pager like `less` to read it in the terminal.